# Como Imponer un prefijo en los valores de un input tipo text de un form que se envía por POST

Tags: formularios, input, text

Necesito que al valor que el usuario agregue a este campo se envie con un prefijo "+" (el símbolo de mas)
`<input class="form-control" placeholder="Celular a 10 digitos *"  id="mobile"  minlength="11" maxlength="11" name="mobile" size="20" type="text"/>`

yo hubiera pensado que era muy fácil pero por mas que he buscado no he encontrado una solución sencilla.

El formulario se envia por medio de post a una aplicacion web a la cual no tengo acceso, solo necesito agregar el "+" al valor que se envia. No es necesario validar que el usuario lo meta

Comment: Agregar el `+` como prefijo mediante programación o validar que el usuario lo haya ingresado??

Comment: Hola Fernando, te refieres a recoger lo introducido por el usuario y añadirle el ```+``` después simplemente o necesitas comprobar que el usuario lo haya introducido???

Comment: Solo es añadirle el "+" al valor del usuario , no es necesario validar si el usuario lo metio o no.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás recogiendo el formulario mediante POST en PHP por ejemplo, podrías realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Recoge el valor del campo de entrada
    $mobileNumber = $_POST["mobile"];

    // Añade el prefijo "+" si la longitud es 10
    if (strlen($mobileNumber) == 10) {
        $mobileNumber = '+' . $mobileNumber;
    }
}
?>
```

La próxima vez intenta indicar de forma más concreta el objetivo, espero te pueda servir. Un saludo.

Comment: Perdón, el problema es que yo no tengo acceso a la app donde recogen los datos, solo necesito enviar la información con el prefijo "+" en ese campo sin necesidad de validar si el usuario lo escribe o no.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas simple es agregar el prefijo `+` en el evento `onsubmit`, algo así

```
<form  method="post" onsubmit="mobile.value = '+' + mobile.value"
```

Ahora si quieres algo más reultizalbe, puedes agregar un atributo `data-prefix` a cada elemento que lo requiera, luego usando el evento `submit` buscas aquellos elementos y lo agregas al valor:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("UnForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", ()=>{
  form.querySelectorAll("[data-prefix]").forEach(el=>{
    el.value= el.dataset.prefix + el.value;
  })
});
```

```html
<form id="UnForm" method="post" action="unapagina">

<input data-prefix="+" class="form-control"  placeholder="Celular a 10 digitos *"  id="mobile"  minlength="11" maxlength="11" name="mobile" size="20"  type="text"/>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```